# Tensorflow 2: how to profile speed of custom layer

Tags: python, tensorflow

Pretty simple and straightforward question: what’s the simplest way to speed test a custom keras layer? To clarify I’m subclassing keras Layer and implementing my logic in tensorflow ops. As it extensively makes use of sparse tensors I’m a little concerned about speed. In standard python I’d probably use something like timeit, but unsure if that works with tensorflow (maybe with eager execution)? Would also be nice to test both cpu and gpu.

Comment: Thought about writing a test case (assume test dataset x) and simply time a call to the layer independent of the network? I.e. using timeit on `layer(x)`.